# I have a Galaxy s4, I changed my pin passcode and used ADMbut it stil won't work

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4, locked-out

I recently changed my pin passcode on my phone, locked it, then tried the code and it unlocked it, so I relocked it. Ten minutes later I tried to unlock it ms it said the passcode was incorrect. I tried numerous times. I looked online, and I tried the android device manager. I locked it once, tried the passcode and it didn't work. I tried it on another android device ms still no success. I really need to find a wayp to get my phone unlocked, it has extremely important information on it. Is there any way to fix this without having to reset it to the factory settings?

Answer (score 0):

If you have your phone rooted you can remove 3 files with the name 'lock settings' in it in /data/system/ . For more help look here: http://youtu.be/TlxixmkjDyE